# count string length c

Tags: c, string, null

```
int string_length(char str[])
{
int i;
for(i=200; i>=0; i--)
{
  //printf("%c \n",str[200]);
   printf("%d",i);
  if(str[i] !=NULL)
 {
    return(i);
   }
  }
}
```

I want to return the proper string size if string is :eee rrr : it should return 7 but this return 200 always

Comment: Undefined behavior for short strings. Why did you think counting backwards starting at 200 would work?

Comment: If you pass in a string of length 7, what, where and why would you want `str[200]` to do ?

Comment: Gotta be a troll, surely?

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?  What do you see when you trace through the code?  (you **did** trace through it, *didn't you?*)

Answer (score 2):

It's because data outside the bounds of the string you pass in is random, and mostly not `'\0'`.

*Never* access an array out of bounds, it causes *undefined behavior*. If you want to make your own function you need to start at the beginning.

And what's wrong with [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one instead. It's more simple

```
int string_length(char *str)
{
    int i =0;
    while(*str++) i++;
    return i;
}
```

and you can use predefined function [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) from `#include <string.h>`

Comment: string_length(NULL) and SIGSEGV

Comment: @jacekmigacz even `strlen()` and `strcmp()` from  `#include <string.h>` does not make the check of NULL pointer. He can make the check outside the function. `if(str) { len = string_length(str); }`

Comment: MOHAMED: sure!, that was comment for user2426801 to let him know

Answer (score 0):

***Sticking as closely as possible to your original code***,

- This function counts from 0-up... not 200-down.
- This function ends when it finds a string-terminator, not NULL

```
int string_length(char str[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<200; ++i)
    {
        printf("[%d] : %c \n", i, str[i]);
        if(str[i] == '\0')
        {
            return(i);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or, if you want a minimalist function:

```
int string_length(char* s)
{
    return (*s)? string_length(s+1)+1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you pass in a 201-length string? You don't cater for every return path.

Comment: @RobbieE:  As I clearly stated, this was written to stay as close to the poster's original code as possible, including his limitations and design choices.

Comment: aberlenky ur code is not work if there is a space between two string

Comment: im doing it that way becuase i want to consider the word like

Comment: if word is 'world begin" it read the space as an empty and only return world

Comment: @user2426801 : I don't know what to tell you, except that you are WRONG.   This code does NOT stop when it encounters a space (ascii-code 32).  It only stops when it encounters an end-of-string marker (`\0` or ascii-code 0).  I have in fact tested this code with spaces between multiple words, and it works fine.   If you feel differently, **POST CODE**, **EXAMPLE INPUT**, and **ACTUAL OUTPUT** that prove your case.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you starting at the 200th character? You have no way of knowing upfront whether this memory address has been allocated or not. You are risking a program crash. Related to this, you're not checking whether the string passed into your function is valid (check that it has a non-null address)

Rather start from index 0 and work your way up.

In c/c++, the end of a string is marked with a '\0' character. Try looking for this one instead of NULL (unless you've defined NULL to be '\0')